# SELECT 3 tables in one query with condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to SELECT 3 table in one query and show all product with price?

Below is my database structure(MySql) :

**categories**

```
+-------------+------------+
 category_id  | parent_id  |
+-------------+------------+
  1           |      0     
  2           |      1
  3           |      1
  4           |      1
  5           |      2
  6           |      3
```

**products_to_categories**

```
+-------------+------------+
 product_id   | category_id|
+-------------+------------+
  54          |      0     
  55          |      2
  56          |      2
  57          |      2
  58          |      3
  59          |      3
  60          |      4
```

**products**

```
+-------------+------------+
 product_id   |    price   |
+-------------+------------+
  54          |      10.50     
  55          |      11.20
  56          |      1.00
  57          |      22.20
  58          |      32.0
  59          |      32.0
  60          |      22.0
```

Below is my condition ;

```
1. table categories : parent_id = '1'  
(result : 2,3,4)

2. table products_to_categories : category_id = result categories(result : 2,3,4) 
(result : 55,56,57,58,59,60)

3. table products : inner join or left join table product to display price where product_id = result products_to_categories(result : 55,56,57,58,59,60)
```

**Final Output**

```
  55 - 11.20
  56 - 1.00
  57 - 22.20
  58 - 32.0
  59 - 32.0
  60 - 22.0
```

Before i post this question here is my previous query(im stuck how to proceed to condition 2)

```
$sql_all = mysql_query("SELECT cat.parent_id,cat.category_id FROM categories cat WHERE cat.parent_id='1' ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_all)) {
echo $row['categories_id'].'<br/>'; 
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT  c.*
FROM    categories a
        INNER JOIN products_to_categories b
            ON a.category_id = b.category_id
        INNER JOIN products c
            ON b.product_id = c.product_id
WHERE  a.parent_id = 1
```

This will display all records from `products` table having `parent_id` = 1.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following query :

```
SELECT pro.product_id, SUM(pro.price) 
FROM categories cat 
JOIN products_to_categories ptc USING(category_id)
JOIN products pro ON ptc.product_id = pro.product_id
WHERE cat.parent_id='1'
```

With the above solution you could easily scale in future, in case you would want to GROUP BY a particular product ...

Answer (score 1):

The following query should bring the results you want.

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.price
FROM products p
JOIN products_to_categories pc ON (pc.product_id = p.product_id)
JOIN categories c ON ((c.category_id = pc.category_id) AND (c.parent_id = "1"))
```

Of course, you can change the `parent_id` from **1** to any other value, and obtain the results accordingly.

Note: I believe that in this case you will get better performance by stating the `parent_id` condition in the JOIN clause instead of the WHERE clause.